# i got this errror in sentry _reportEvent is not defined

Tags: reactjs

The given abs_path of the stack frame is chrome-extension://dbilanlcioamaadkbepcenpombaejbla/dist/parse_window.js which doesn't match any release artifact. Read our docs for troubleshooting help

i didn't find how to stop it

Answer (score 0):

> Usually these errors originate from browser extensions that your users are using. You can filter these out with the denyUrls option: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/filtering/#decluttering-sentry

From: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/5289#issuecomment-1604158912